# How to determine dielectric constant and loss tanget of a PCB board at a specific frequency?

Tags: rf, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, microwave, dielectric

I need to know dielectric constant (relative permittivity) and Tan loss of a FR4 board at 2.45 GHz.

The specification of the manufacturer is as it is below:

**Dielectric Constant:**

- Test method (IPC-TM-650): 2.5.5.2
- Test condition: Etched/@1 MHz
- Specification(IPC-4101C) <5.4
- Typical value: 4.58

**Loss Tanget:**
 - Test method (IPC-TM-650): 2.5.5.2 
 - Test condition: Etched/@1 MHz 
 - Specification(IPC-4101C) < 0.035
 - Typical value: 0.022

I read on the Net that those values should be lower at higher frequencies. Is it possible to calculate/determine/predict those two values for 2.45 GHz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are equations to calculate them. Look here: http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/news/4_5.htm.